# Куда следует добавить выражение WHERE в SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql

Есть MySQL запрос, который возвращает все комменты.
Но мне нужно, чтобы возвращал только те, где поле `comments.is_active=1`. Не получается подправить, уже замучался, постоянно:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax ...

Куда добавить `WHERE c.is_active=1`?

```
SELECT c.id_comment, c.id_parent, u.login, n.title_news, cat.category_name, 
c.`comment`, c.date_time, c.is_active FROM comments c 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.id_user
    LEFT JOIN news n ON n.id_news = c.id_news 
    LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id_category = n.id_category 
        ORDER BY c.date_time DESC LIMIT {$start},{$limit};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный запрос на выборку (**SELECT**) в SQL в большинстве случаев состоит или может состоять из следующих операторов:

```
SELECT колонки
FROM таблицы
JOIN таблица
WHERE условия
GROUP BY колонки
HAVING условие
ORDER BY колонки
```

*Более подробную спецификацию SELECT для MySQL можно получить [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).*

**Изменение порядка не допускается**. Следовательно, исходя из приведенного примера, условие WHERE у вас должно идти после JOIN'ов:

```
SELECT c.id_comment,
       c.id_parent,
       u.login,
       n.title_news,
       cat.category_name,
       c.`comment`,
       c.date_time,
       c.is_active
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.id_user
LEFT JOIN news n ON n.id_news = c.id_news
LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id_category = n.id_category
WHERE c.is_active=1
ORDER BY c.date_time DESC
LIMIT {$start},{$limit};
```